# How to implement pagination in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How do i implement pagination in salesforce.
I have a VF page which uses a custom controller which retrieves records and displays it on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look @ http://www.chiragmehta.info/chirag/2009/11/24/salesforce-visualforce-pagination-with-apex/

Answer (score 0):

The new SOQL Offset technology may help you out:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/01/soql-offset-in-spring-12.html